# Convert a BERT Model to TFLite

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, bert-language-model

I have this code for semantic search engine built using the pre-trained bert model. I want to convert this model into tflite for deploying it to google mlkit. I want to know how to convert it. I want to know if its even possible to convert this into tflite. It might be because its mentioned on the official tensorflow site :https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert. But I dont know where to begin

Code:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

# Load the BERT model. Various models trained on Natural Language Inference (NLI) https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/docs/pretrained-models/nli-models.md and 
# Semantic Textual Similarity are available https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/docs/pretrained-models/sts-models.md

model = SentenceTransformer('bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')

# A corpus is a list with documents split by sentences.

sentences = ['Absence of sanity', 
             'Lack of saneness',
             'A man is eating food.',
             'A man is eating a piece of bread.',
             'The girl is carrying a baby.',
             'A man is riding a horse.',
             'A woman is playing violin.',
             'Two men pushed carts through the woods.',
             'A man is riding a white horse on an enclosed ground.',
             'A monkey is playing drums.',
             'A cheetah is running behind its prey.']

# Each sentence is encoded as a 1-D vector with 78 columns
sentence_embeddings = model.encode(sentences)

print('Sample BERT embedding vector - length', len(sentence_embeddings[0]))

print('Sample BERT embedding vector - note includes negative values', sentence_embeddings[0])

#@title Sematic Search Form

# code adapted from https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/examples/application_semantic_search.py

query = 'Nobody has sane thoughts' #@param {type: 'string'}

queries = [query]
query_embeddings = model.encode(queries)

# Find the closest 3 sentences of the corpus for each query sentence based on cosine similarity
number_top_matches = 3 #@param {type: "number"}

print("Semantic Search Results")

for query, query_embedding in zip(queries, query_embeddings):
    distances = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist([query_embedding], sentence_embeddings, "cosine")[0]

    results = zip(range(len(distances)), distances)
    results = sorted(results, key=lambda x: x[1])

    print("\n\n======================\n\n")
    print("Query:", query)
    print("\nTop 5 most similar sentences in corpus:")

    for idx, distance in results[0:number_top_matches]:
        print(sentences[idx].strip(), "(Cosine Score: %.4f)" % (1-distance))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to have your model in TensorFlow, the package you are using is written in PyTorch. Huggingface's [Transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) has TensorFlow models that you can start with. In addition, they also have [TFLite-ready models](https://github.com/huggingface/tflite-android-transformers) for Android.

In general, you have a TensorFlow model first. Them, save it in the `SavedModel` format:

```py
tf.saved_model.save(pretrained_model, "/tmp/pretrained-bert/1/")
```

You can run the converter on this.

Comment: I have used a pre-trained tensorflow model, universal sentence encoder for semantic search. How can I convert that to tfite?

Comment: Are you using code from this package: https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py ?

Comment: no. this is my model code : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1P7E2xLzwQ5eSQYxQ3dc2DL_gdz69mq_O

Comment: can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried run the convert tool (tflite_convert) and did it complain anything?

BTW, you may want to check out the QA example from TFLite team which use a Bert Model. https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/bert_qa/android

Comment: They use MobileBERT by the way, see https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/bert_qa/overview

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any information about using a BERT model to obtain document embeddings on mobile and compute a k-nearest documents search, as in your example. It might also not be a good idea because BERT models can be expensive to execute and have a large number of parameters so a large model file size (400mb+) as well.

However, [you can now use](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/09/whats-new-in-tensorflow-lite-for-nlp.html) BERT and MobileBERT for text classification and question answering on mobile. Maybe you can start with their [demo app](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/bert_qa/android) which interfaces with a MobileBERT tflite model, as Xunkai mentioned. I am sure in the near future there will be better support for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an official PyTorch extractor for Onnx or tflite
https://huggingface.co/docs/optimum/exporters/tflite/usage_guides/export_a_model

```
optimum-cli export tflite --model bert-base-uncased --sequence_length 128 bert_tflite/
```

Replace `bert-base-uncased` with your choice of the model hostel on hugging face.